# Is it possible to display 3d models on desktop for Android devices with Android Studio or Unity?

Tags: android, android-studio, unity-game-engine

As shown in the title, I’m trying to display a 3D model created with Blender  for Android terminal by using Android Studio or Unity. no matter how much I research, I cant find the way for it.
If you can display it, I would appreciate it if you could tell me how.

Comment: What do you mean "display a 3D model"? Display it where? By "desktop", do you mean "launcher"?

Comment: you mean in app or wallpaper?

Comment: I mean I wanna display a 3D model to the home screen on Android smart phone. So, I mean outside of app.

Comment: Take a screenshot and set as wallpaper. This desktop is OS, so Android Studio or Unity won't help